# Rails 5.1, group_by, parse date, i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, group-by, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a very specific problem to get the month name in I18n. I'm grouping some infos per month and year, and it looks like that when I want to translate it, all the month with a specific caracter like é or û aren't working, where the rest is. Let me show you how it looks like :

Helper :

```
def user_spendings_paginate
    user.spendings.all.order('date DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
end

def grouped_spendings
    user_spendings_paginate.group_by{ |t| t.date.to_date == DateTime.now.to_date } 
end

def month_wise_sorted_spendings
    if user_spendings_paginate.present?
       user_spendings_paginate.group_by{ |t| t("date.month_names")[t.date.month] + " " + t.date.year.to_s }
    end     
end
```

So as you can see, I call all the user.spendings. I group them twice, the first to get the date of the day and the other to get the rest per month and year. As you can see I i18n the month name. In my yml file I have that :

```
month_names:
-
- Janvier
- Février
- Mars
- Avril
- Mai
- Juin
- Juillet
- Aout
- Septembre
- Octobre
- Novembre
- Decembre
```

I tried to remove the é from Décembre and the û from Août to try, but the problem remains the same.

My controller :

```
if params[:month]
    @date = Date.parse("#{params[:month]}")
else
    flash[:error] = t(".something_wrong")
    redirect_to myspendings_path(locale: I18n.locale)
end
```

And my view :

```
<% date_in_link = " #{month}" %>
      <p><%= link_to myspendingsdetail_path(:month => month, locale: I18n.locale), class: "btn btn-secondary" do %>
      <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
      <%= date_in_link %>
      <% end %>
```

So basically what I'm doing is that I group the spendings per month and year. Then I loop trough all the user.spendings and I add this part of code above in the mix so you have a link according the date that you can click and sends you to a new page whith more infos just about this month of the year.
It works, but just for the month with no specific caracters. If I try with Février I got this as a message : `invalid date` for @date in the controller.
I assume it is coming from the special caracter as the rest is working.

I hope the explanation are clear, I tried my best. If you need more stuff let me know.

I think that the @date variable is missing something, but I'm not sure. Anybody to help ?

EDIT :

My url looks like this when it works :

```
http://localhost:3000/fr/myspendingsdetail?month=Janvier+2018
```

When it doesnt work :

```
http://localhost:3000/fr/myspendingsdetail?month=Decembre+2018
```

Interesting but when I put the month like this :

```
http://localhost:3000/fr/myspendingsdetail?month=12+2018
```

It works, so it's really a caracter problem

EDIT 2 :

Well it works... if I put 12 he bring me on february, same for 2, but if I put 1 for january same error as before, invalid date.

Comment: Ok so finally I don't understand where the problem is coming from. I tried Décembre, of course in my URL I have that : `http://localhost:3000/fr/myspendingsdetail?month=Décembre+2018`, because of the é that's a no go, but if I change it to that : `http://localhost:3000/fr/myspendingsdetail?month=Decembre+2018` it works, where before it didn't... I don't get it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES ! I got it !

I share my answer in case anybody needs it once.

I changed my helper :

```
user_spendings_paginate.group_by{ |t| (Date::MONTHNAMES[t.date.month] + " " + t.date.year.to_s) }
```

I keep the names of the month in english in the background, if I can say...

Then the view :

```
<% date_in_link = " #{month}" %>
      <p><%= link_to myspendingsdetail_path(:month => month, locale: I18n.locale), class: "btn btn-secondary" do %>
      <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
      <%= l date_in_link.to_date, format: :pdf %>
      <% end %>
```

As I get a String out of my helper, and I pass that trough params with my links I thought that it was there that I should change the language. So I wrote this : 
`l date_in_link.to_date, format: :pdf` and in my yml file I went for a custom format like so : `pdf: "%B %Y"` for month and year.

Result :

(link)Février 2018
- spending
- spending
(link)Janvier 2018
- spending
- spending

And when I click on the link it passes the params in english but who cares. On the next page I got the date back in the language I want anyway. Mission complete !